# how to arrange different values in arrays in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, compare

i have this situation:

```
print_r($key);echo'<br>'; 
foreach($value as $test){
print_r(count($test));echo'<br>'; 
}
echo'<br>';
```

witch returns:

```
Jerome Frier
2
5
1

Luke Saora
5
4
6

Tracy Edion
6
1
4
```

what i am aiming for is to display the maximum value for each name, like this:

```
Jerome Frier          Luke Saora           Tracy Edion
    6                     5                     6
```

basically taking the maximum value for each name comparing each row..

does this sound confuse... :)

thanks

Comment: It does confuse me that your maximum value eventually is 6 for Jerome and 5 for Luke while it should be vice versa... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd just make use of PHP's [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function. If the first and only parameter is an array, max() returns the highest value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, max() returns the biggest of these values.

So either you put all the values in an array and throw it into the `max()` function, or you insert them one by one..

```
$max = max($your_values); //where $your_values is an array
//or
$max = max($value1, $value2, $value3); //where $value is a single value
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems as if there are two nested foreach loops, am i right?

Maybe you try this out, it´s not tested but anyways:

```
$array = $your_array;
$compare = array();

foreach($array as $key => $personScoreArray){
      $compare[$key] = max($personScoreArray);

}
```

Then you can do what ever you want with the values in the $compare array.
For a better solution a bit more code or a more spcific question would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you're after (assuming `$arr` is your outer array):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . '<br />' . max($value) . '<br /><br />';
}
```